# Retrieve EntityID for MarketingList in CRM2011

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm sure someone can help me out here, I'm really much ripping my hair out why my code below doesn't work. Basically I have a custom entity wich has a list (and all its list members inside the list) with my custom entity(registerd on post-create) I create another list which imports all those list members into another list. Now I need to retrieve the entityID for each list member (in order for me to add them) My code below (just for one list member for testing purposes):

```
// GET LIST MEMBER 
QueryByAttribute query = new QueryByAttribute("listmember");
query.AddAttributeValue("listid", m_list_ID.Id);
ColumnSet cs = new ColumnSet();
cs.AddColumns("entityid");
query.ColumnSet = cs;
EntityCollection entityCollection = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);


Guid g = Guid.Empty;
g = (Guid)entityCollection.Entities[0].Attributes["entityid"];
```

To check the guid I output the GUID on another field as a string just to check if it has th right one, but when I try to save the form I get the error "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.". On another note I'm sure it retrieves the entities as I have done a count, and it shows the right number of entities but doesn't allow me to grab the entityId attribute for some reason. Would appreciate if somone could explain what is going on here. Thank in advance.

Comment: When you debug into this, what line throws the InvalidCastException?

Comment: Hi Ben, I tried using debug bur for some reason I get a stupid error on that as well when I upload the logfile. What is really confusing to me is when I do the same thing but use "listmemberid" from the listmember table I get the GUID for that it just throws an exception when I try to grab the entityid. I'm sure the code is fine I assume there is something else you have to do :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `entityid` attribute of the `listmember` entity is of type `EntityReference`. If you change your cast to `EntityReference`, you can reference the GUID via the `Id` property.